# How do I check the type of data read on cin?

Tags: c++, input, types

More specifically, I want to make sure this type is a double (or int/float). I have searched near and far and found pretty much zero non-rigorous solutions. I want to only use code that I can fully understand, being a complete beginner at C++.

In Java, I can simply do something like this:

```
ArrayList<Double> data = new ArrayList<Double>();
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
while (in.hasNextDouble()) {
        double x = in.nextDouble();
        data.add(x); 
        n += 1;      
        sum += x;    
}  
double average = sum / n;
```

C++ is clearly a different story. Here's what I tried:

```
vector<double> data;
while (looping) 
{
    cin >> x;
    if (typeid(x) != typeid(float) && typeid(x) != typeid(double) &&
        typeid(x) != typeid(int))
            {looping = false; break;}
    data.push_back(x);
    n += 1;
    sum += x;
}
double average = sum / n;
```

This doesn't work. The loop keeps going as doubles are entered, but once I enter something that's not a double the code simply stops and doesn't advance onward. I'm pretty crestfallen. Any suggestions?

Comment: `typeid(x)` depends on the *type* of `x`, which is determined by what you declared `x` to be in the first place.

Comment: How do you differentiate between an inputted int, float and double? For example, if I input 2.0, then what would you consider it to be?

Comment: juanchopanza: So then how do I check if the user's input isn't a double?

Comment: The user input is a character string, always. You get to decide which rules to apply to determine what type to instantiate from it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

User doesn't "enter a variable". She enters a string. And operator `>>` when supplied with a float variable tries to interpret this string as a textual representation of a floating-point number.

It may or may not succeed: in Java, failure would cause `nextDouble()` to throw an exception. In C++, stream operations don't throw; instead failure means that `cin.good()` will start to return `false`.

```
float x;
cin >> x;
while (cin.good()) 
{   
    data.push_back(x);
    n += 1;
    sum += x;
    cin >> x;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if x is declared as double, your if condition would fail and hence the while loop is broken

Comment: No? (typeid(x) != typeid(float) && typeid(x) != typeid(double) && typeid(x) != typeid(int)) returns true if x is a double.

Comment: Read your statement again, you are combining everything with logical AND and one of your conditions is that x shouldn't be of type double. If it is of type double this condition can't be fullfilled and therefore the whole condition, because ANDed, evaluates to false.

Answer (score 0):

You have several solutions here. I will post 2 of them. The first solution needs c++11 standard due to `stod` function. You can do this passing `-std=c++11` flag to `gcc` or `clang++`. Microsoft compiler enables c++11 by default.

**Solution 1**. It consists of reading in a string all the time through `cin >> input_string` and using standard c++11 function `stod`. stod stands for string to double. If `stod` fails to parse a `double`, it will throw an `std::invalid_argument` exception.

This solution would be like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <numeric>
#include <string>
#include <stdexcept>

using namespace std;


int main() {
   vector<double> vec;
   string input;
   try {
      while (getline(cin, input)) {
         vec.push_back(stod(input));

      }
   }
   catch (std::invalid_argument &) {
      cout << "Invalid argument caught\n";
      //Failed to parse a double
   }
   //If pressed Ctrl+D (in linux, which sends EOF), failbit and eofbit are set
   //If it is through invalid_argument the way the loop was exit, then,
   //eof and failbit are not set and cin can be used without clearing.
   double average = accumulate(vec.begin(), vec.end(), 0.0)/vec.size();
   cout << "EOF: " << cin.eof() << endl;
   cout << "Fail: " << cin.fail() << endl;

   //Clean eof and failbit to be able to use cin again
   cin.clear();
   cout << "EOF after cleaning: " << cin.eof() << endl;
   cout << "Fail after cleaning: " << cin.fail() << endl;

   cout << average << endl;
```

}

EDIT: I tested and when you put more than one number per line it will just get the first one without throwing `std::invalid_argument`. It will throw an `std::invalid_argument` only when you start a line when the line starts with a non-double. This is because the `stod` function behaves like this: [stod reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stof).

Note that this solution only allows to read one double per line.

**Solution 2**. Read using `cin >> input_double` directly. This can fail. Please note that `iostream`s don't use exceptios by default in c++. You can activate them with the api, but I don't recommend you to do it because you can manage all error handling locally.

You can read any number of doubles separated by any space characters:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <numeric>
#include <limits>

using namespace std;


int main() {
   double x = 0.0;
   vector<double> data;

   //cin will fail to read the first non-double in the input.
   //You can input as many doubles as you wish. Spaces will
   //be ignored. At the first non-double, cin will fail to read
   //and will exit the loop, setting istream::failbit.
   //Alternatively, you can send EOF (Linux is Ctrl+D) and the loop also will finish.
   while (cin >> x) {
      data.push_back(x);

   }
   double average = accumulate(data.begin(), data.end(), 0.0)/data.size();

   //If you wanted to use again cin, you should:
   //1. Clear failbit. You can do like this:
   cin.clear();

   //2. Cleaning the remaining input. Will stop when finding end of line.
   string rubbish;
   geline(cin, rubbish);
   //cin is usable here again if you need it and with the input clean already.


   cout << average << '\n';
}
```

You can give something like this in the input, in one line:

1 2.4 -38.7 5.8 28.9 hello.

What will happen? The loop will consume until 28.9, stopping at hello. After that, failbit is set. We clean failbit to be able to continue reading until the end of the line. Since hello is considered "rubbish" because we wanted to read doubles, we clean it with a `getline` and we can use `cin` again without trouble.